# Why can't I see my data from my drop down list saved in my database on myphp?

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started programming so im pretty new to this!

Why can't I see my data from my drop down list saved in my database on myphp?

My code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend> Selecteer uw Categorie </legend>

    NieuweCategorie:

    <input name="NieuweCategorie" type="radio" class="form_1" value="Y" onclick="
    if(document.getElementById('NameNew').disabled==true)
    {
        document.getElementById('NameNew').disabled=false
    }
    if(document.getElementById('aa').disabled==false)
    {
        document.getElementById('aa').disabled=true
    }   

    "/>Yes
    <input name="NieuweCategorie" type="radio" class="form_1" checked="True" value="N" onclick="
    if(document.getElementById('NameNew').disabled==false)
    {
        document.getElementById('NameNew').disabled=true
    }
    if(document.getElementById('aa').disabled==true)
    {
        document.getElementById('aa').disabled=false
    }
    "/>No


    <br><br>Invoeren :<input name="NameNew" id="NameNew" type="text" size="25" maxlength="40" disabled="disabled" />


<label for="Selecteer"> Selecteer </label>

<select name="aa" id="aa">

<datalist id="Categorie">
<Option Value="Router" Input value= "Router">Router</option>
<Option Value="Switch">Switch</option>
<Option Value="Toestel">Toestel</option>
<Option Value="Basisstation">Basisstation</option>
<Option Value="Repeaters">Repeaters</option>
</select>
</datalist>
</fieldset>
```

On phpmyadmin I am seeing all data from the rest of my html script Only this Categorie fieldset isnt showing for me!

What database table structure should I set for this field? (I tried SET/ENUM and VARCHAR) Or have i done something wrong in my code maybe?

Thnak you kindly in advanced for ur attention and help!
Much appreciated!

(I would post an image but I recently joined this awesome community and only have 1 Reputation point so far :-D )

Comment: I don't see any PHP here...

Comment: This script is written in Dutch! I hope this doens't make it impossible to help me! Basically the script makes an option which allows u to select wheter u want to enter a new item or select on from a drop down list!
If u press yes, U should write the item where if u press no u can select from items alrdy in the drop down list!
This is for an inventory program

Comment: Still not seeing any PHP, how this relates to PHP or how this relates to a database.

Comment: You can separate the javascript code from the tags to a method and invoke method on hte onclick call.

Comment: I am a native dutch speaker, so I understand everything in the code. Problem is, there are no PHP tags so everything is read as HTML. You need to put PHP code between "<?php" and "?>". I see you have some Javascript code, but that can't get your info from the database.

Comment: In all honesty, this looks to be too difficult for you to make. You first need to work a bit more with PHP and HTML before you can work with databases.

Comment: I am using a Post form along with 
<?php
require_once 'Connect2db.php';
?>
I believe u when u say it  might be difficult but this is how my internship works ;D Trial and error mode all the way!

Comment: Maybe your query isn't escaped properly for fieldset.

Comment: Maybe you should write a query to fetch the data and loop the recordset to populate your combolist. Also try to move your javascript to seperate file and perhaps look into jquery.

Comment: deceze, SidCool,  Parrotmaster and DarkBee, Ty kindly for the tips! I will continue my epic research and try to see if i can comprehend what u are refering too!
Ty for ur fast replies! I understand this might require A LOT of explanation since I am a newbie in programmign still :)
Big Ups to this webiste! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the closing tags for `</datalist>` and `</select>` the wrong way round is one possibility although it still appears to work that way on FF.

Mainly there was a bit of a mess here: `<Option Value="Router" Input value= "Router">Router</option>`. If that is tidied up it should works.

```
<select list="Categorie" name="aa" id="aa">
   <datalist id="Categorie">
       <Option Value="Router">Router</option>
       <Option Value="Switch">Switch</option>
       <Option Value="Toestel">Toestel</option>
       <Option Value="Basisstation">Basisstation</option>
       <Option Value="Repeaters">Repeaters</option>
   </datalist>
</select>
```

Comment: Ty RiggsFolly! I will try this out! Much appreciated!

Comment: Dear RiggsFolly, For some reason after adjusting these changes to try it out, I am now no longer to select my options from the drop down list! I wonder whether this is due to some coding u might have left out? Or due to my script having more flaws? 

Just to be clear, I was alrdy able to save data into my database but just for this particular field "Categorie" I can't. 
Isn't it true that a script can be written how ever as long as it works, but that the database fields have to be the same !?!

Comment: @Kentje WOOPPSS. Sorry .. typo. I have changed the answer. I had a <input> open tag and a </select> close tag. Sorry!

Comment: Aha ok :) Mistakes happen! Cheers! :)